# Combining Variance and Sum of Variance Law

Tags: variance, standard-deviation

Let's say I want to find the find out how much time my classmates spent preparing for their classes.

I collected data from 10 people, and found out the standard deviation is 0.8 hours with a mean of 2.4 hours.

But, later I felt that the sample size was too small, so I collected data from another 5 people, now with a standard deviation of 1.2 hours and a mean of 2 hours.

So, I want to combine these 2 data sets together.

By sum of variance law Var(X ± Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y), for indepedent X and Y. Hence, the combined standard deviation is s = ((1.2^2) + (0.8^2))^(1/2) = 1.44.

However, when I recomputed the standard variance from scratch using sample variance, I got a value of s = 0.93.

Why is this so? Am still trying to figure out when it is appropriate to use the sum of variance law.

Comment: Summing random variables that represent the same object is not the same thing as "combining" their data generating process. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ represent standard 6-sided dice throws (same dice, different samples). Define $Z = X + Y$. $Z$ does not represent a 6-sided standard dice throw, in fact$Z$ may be seen as the throw of a 11-sided dice that goes from 2 to 12 .  When you sum $X$ and $Y$, you are creating a new RV defined as such.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't sum $X+Y$. Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{15}$, you already compute the following estimators:
$$\bar{X}_1=\frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^{10}X_i,\qquad\bar{X}_2=\frac{1}{5}\sum_{i=11}^{15}X_i$$
$$S_1^2=\frac{1}{9}\sum_{i=1}^{10}\left(X_i-\bar{X}_1\right)^2,\qquad S_2^2=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=11}^{15}\left(X_i-\bar{X}_2\right)^2$$
Now you want to compute
$$\bar{X}=\frac{1}{15}\sum_{i=1}^{15}X_i,\qquad S^2=\frac{1}{14}\sum_{i=1}^{15}\left(X_i-\bar{X}\right)^2$$
It is false your hypothesis of $S^2=S_1^2+S_2^2$, but you can solve the estimators as:
$$\bar{X}=\frac{1}{15}\left(10\bar{X}_1+5\bar{X}_2\right)$$
$$S^2=\frac{9S_1^2+4S_2^2}{14}$$